# Nodes they have reference to the nodes of current user

Tags: views, nodes

I use node reference and want to display with views to the user only the nodes they have reference to its nodes :

A*<----B

^----C

E**<-----D

*: node created by the current user.

**: node created by an other user.

The views for current user will only show : B,C.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display to a particular user any nodes that are referencing any nodes that they have created? Sorry, this question just reads a little bit funny - just want to get clarification :-)

Comment: yes "nodes that are referencing any nodes that current user have created" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using a view Relationship.

- In **Relationships**, add the content field that you are using as a node reference. This should be something like: Content: Reference (field_parent_node).
- When editing the new relationship, make sure **Require this relationship** is checked.
- In **Fields**, Add the corresponding fields that you want in your view. When selecting node fields, like **Node: Title**, be sure to set the **Relationship** to be the name of your relationship. In my example, this would be **Reference**.
- In **Filters**, add filter **User: Current**.
- When editing this filter, set the **Relationship** to be the name of your relationship (example: **Reference**) and set the **Is the logged in user** to be **Yes**.

I tested this briefly and it worked for creating a view that only lists the node references authored by the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have the view. In it under 'Advanced' add a contextual filter on Content:Author:UID. When you configure the filter select 'Provide default value' under 'When the filter value is NOT available' and set the Type to 'User ID from currently logged in user'. This will limit the display to nodes the current user created.

EDIT:

Misunderstood. If you are trying to create a list if nodes which reference the current node (eg, view displayed as a block when the page is displayed) the method is the same. Create a view of the nodes, and a Contextual filter on the Node Reference field. The default value type should then be set to 'Content ID from URL'. This will limit the list to those nodes which refer to the current node.

Comment: But the current user created A not B and C, you will only show A with you views !